# Problems with column labels after importing a csv file

Tags: r

I'm trying to import an anova data set csv file into R using the read.csv function. When I import it the columns are labelled X........ Even though the csv file the column labels are clearly person, gender etc

I don't know why this is. I've copied the code below. Any help would be appreciated

> read.csv("/Users/Desktop/R /anova data set.csv")

X.......

1  ;Person;gender;Age;Height;pre.weight;Diet;weight6weeks

2                                    ;25; ;41;171;60;2;60
3                                  ;26; ;32;174;103;2;103
4                                   ;1;0;22;159;58;1;54.2
5                                     ;2;0;46;192;60;1;54
6                                   ;3;0;55;170;64;1;63.3
7                                   ;4;0;33;171;64;1;61.1
8                                   ;5;0;50;170;65;1;62.2
9                                     ;6;0;50;201;66;1;64
10                                    ;7;0;37;174;67;1;65
11                                  ;8;0;28;176;69;1;60.5
12                                  ;9;0;28;165;70;1;68.1
13                                 ;10;0;45;165;70;1;66.9
14                                 ;11;0;60;173;72;1;70.5
15                                   ;12;0;48;156;72;1;69
16                                 ;13;0;41;163;72;1;68.4
17                                 ;14;0;37;167;82;1;81.1
18                                 ;27;0;44;174;58;2;60.1
19                                   ;28;0;37;172;58;2;56
20                                 ;29;0;41;165;59;2;57.3
21                                 ;30;0;43;171;61;2;56.7
22                                   ;31;0;20;169;62;2;55
23                                 ;32;0;51;174;63;2;62.4
24                                 ;33;0;31;163;63;2;60.3
25                                 ;34;0;54;173;63;2;59.4
26                                   ;35;0;50;166;65;2;62
27                                   ;36;0;48;163;66;2;64
28                                 ;37;0;16;165;68;2;63.8
29                                 ;38;0;37;167;68;2;63.3
30                                 ;39;0;30;161;76;2;72.7
31                                 ;40;0;29;169;77;2;77.5
32                                   ;52;0;51;165;60;3;53
33                                 ;53;0;35;169;62;3;56.4
34                                 ;54;0;21;159;64;3;60.6
35                                 ;55;0;22;169;65;3;58.2
36                                 ;56;0;36;160;66;3;58.2
37                                 ;57;0;20;169;67;3;61.6
38                                 ;58;0;35;163;67;3;60.2
39                                 ;59;0;45;155;69;3;61.8
40                                   ;60;0;58;141;70;3;63
41                                 ;61;0;37;170;70;3;62.7
42                                 ;62;0;31;170;72;3;71.1
43                                 ;63;0;35;171;72;3;64.4
44                                 ;64;0;56;171;73;3;68.9
45                                 ;65;0;48;153;75;3;68.7
46                                   ;66;0;41;157;76;3;71
47                                 ;15;1;39;168;71;1;71.6
48                                 ;16;1;31;158;72;1;70.9
49                                 ;17;1;40;173;74;1;69.5
50                                 ;18;1;50;160;78;1;73.9
51                                   ;19;1;43;162;80;1;71
52                                 ;20;1;25;165;80;1;77.6
53                                 ;21;1;52;177;83;1;79.1
54                                 ;22;1;42;166;85;1;81.5
55                                 ;23;1;39;166;87;1;81.9
56                                 ;24;1;40;190;88;1;84.5
57                                 ;41;1;51;191;71;2;66.8
58                                 ;42;1;38;199;75;2;72.6
59                                 ;43;1;54;196;75;2;69.2
60                                 ;44;1;33;190;76;2;72.5
61                                 ;45;1;45;160;78;2;72.7
62                                 ;46;1;37;194;78;2;76.3
63                                 ;47;1;44;163;79;2;73.6
64                                 ;48;1;40;171;79;2;72.9
65                                 ;49;1;37;198;79;2;71.1
66                                 ;50;1;39;180;80;2;81.4
67                                 ;51;1;31;182;80;2;75.7
68                                 ;67;1;36;155;71;3;68.5
69                                 ;68;1;47;179;73;3;72.1
70                                 ;69;1;29;166;76;3;72.5
71                                 ;70;1;37;173;78;3;77.5
72                                 ;71;1;31;177;78;3;75.2
73                                 ;72;1;26;179;78;3;69.4
74                                 ;73;1;40;179;79;3;74.5
75                                 ;74;1;35;183;83;3;80.2
76                                 ;75;1;49;177;84;3;79.9
77                                 ;76;1;28;164;85;3;79.7
78                                 ;77;1;40;167;87;3;77.8
79                                 ;78;1;51;175;88;3;81.9

> colnames(aov)
> [1] "X......."

Comment: Try `read.csv2("/Users/daviddowney/Desktop/R/anova data set.csv")` -- your columns seem to be separated by semi-colons rather than commas. `read.csv2` will look for semicolons while `read.csv` just looks for commas

Comment: Thanks that worked really well. The table looks much better, but I'm still stuck with the column names X.1, X.2 etc When I try to rename I get errors

    X    X.1    X.2 X.3    X.4        X.5  X.6          X.7

1  NA Person gender Age Height pre.weight Diet weight6weeks

Comment: The `read.csv2` function is looking for column headings in the first row, but `1` is not a valid heading. If you delete it and the semicolon after it, the first value will be treated as a row number. Otherwise change it to V1 or something starting with a character.